# Merge two data frames in R and find common values and non-matching values

Tags: r, match, dataframe

I am trying to find a function to match two data frames of different lengths on one common column only, and create a different column which specifies if it found a match or not.
So, for example,
df1 is:

```
Name Position location
francesca A 75
cristina B 36
```

And df2 is:

```
location Country
75 UK
56 Austria
```

And I would like to match on "Location" and the output to be something like:

```
Name Position Location Match
francesca A 75 1
cristina B 36 0
```

I have tried with the function `match` or with:

```
subset(df1, location %in% df2)
```

But it does not work.

Could you please help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
df1$match <- match(df1$location, df2$location, nomatch=0)
```

This will add a column to df1 indicating which row in df2 matches it (considering only location as you specified).  If there are no matches, zero will be returned, so you get:

```
> df1
       Name Position location match 
1 francesca        A       75     1
2  cristina        B       36     0
```

One caution:  if there are multiple matches in the second table, you'd want to use a different approach as this method only returns the first match.  I assume these are unique because of the way you specified your question, so this should not be an issue.

Comment: Jason B, THANK YOU very much. This way I could get a list of the records matching in both dfs (if match>0), and also a list of the records that are present in only df1 (match==0). Just a further question, do you know if there is a simple way to also have the list of records that are in df2 that are not in df1? Thank you

Comment: Hi @user971102 - glad it worked for you (if the answer solved your problem, please accept it so others will know).  To get records from df2 that aren't in df1, try: df2[which(is.na(match(df2$location, df1$location))),]  Or, more intuitively, df2[-which(df2$location %in% df1$location),]

Comment: Sorry Jason B, just one last clarification...As you said that this method would not work if the values are not unique, I had an extra step in the beginning to make sure there is only one record for 'location' by doing: df1_unique<-subset(df1, !duplicated(location)), for both df1 and df2. But shouldn't this mean that there should be only 0 or 1 values for 'match' column? But my values for 'match' are not only = to 1 or 0...

Comment: @user971102-no worries.  `df1$match` is giving the row in `df2` that matches `location` in `df1`.  If you just want zeros and ones, you can add a step:  `df1$match<-ifelse(df1$match>0,1,0)` or, perhaps it would be better to use logicals: `df1$match=as.logical(df1$match)`